# Creating a report for Accounts and the Contacts Related

Tags: lightning, community, reporting

I am trying to create a report that lists the Accounts with a certain field filter, but also the Contacts within each of the respective Account listed as well. While I can accomplish the first part and create a report with the respective Accounts I can not figure out how to get a list of those Contacts listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Accounts with Contacts Report type and Group By Account Name.

I hope this helps :)